# Why is my state not updating in another state?

Tags: reactjs

Wy state is not updating in another state, I don't know how I can fix this problem.

I wanna do a multiplayer card game with Socket.io, but I run into this problem. Whenever the selectColor state is changing, it's not going to update in the other state. I tried to print the state whenever I click on the component, but the state is just equal as the initial state. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
const [id, setId] = useState();
const [color, setColor] = useState("?");
const [selectColor, setSelectColor] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("id", (id) => setId(id));
    socket.on("forceDisconnect", () => setId("Full"));
    socket.on("cards", (data) => {
        setKarten([
            data.map((element) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        onClick={() =>
                            console.log(selectColor)
                        }
                        key={element}
                    >
                        <Card card={element} />
                    </div>
                );
            }),
        ]);
    });
    socket.on("selectColor", () => {
        setSelectColor(true);
        console.log("selectColor");
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Did you translate some part of code ? e.g. `setSelectFarbe` and `setSelectColro`. or `setKarten` and `setCards`

Comment: i advice to put ***debugger*** point in the same place before *setId* to see if it move to taht point or not

Answer (score 0):

You have created a closure and placed the value of `selectColor` in it when your `socket.on("cards", etc. )` callback was executed (which is therefore 'frozen in time').

It is no good to create your react elements when your data arrives and store them away in your state. You are supposed to create them when your render function is called. Something like so:

```
socket.on("cards", (data) => setCards(data));


return (
  <>
  { cards.map(
    card => (
      <div onClick={() => console.log(selectColor)} key={card}>
        <Card card={card} />
      </div>
    )
  )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Yea now its working. Thank you very much Martin